# Number of downloads icon on play store not showing up

Tags: android, google-play

I've published my Android game on Tuesday (5 days back) and still the downloads/Installs are not updated in the app page. However, the Dev console shows that there have been around 1500 installs. What is the issue? Is this normal?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's best suited for Google support

Answer (score 4):

Google play store always have delays. Just wait, it will update automatically in few days.

Comment: Does this affect the ranking of my game or its just the stats are not displayed?

Comment: It's just a status. It's not affect the ranking.

Answer (score 1):

When you say it's not updated so you mean on the play store on your device? on web? If it's on the device then try clearing the data of Google Play - but if it's not showing up in on the web (I mean your app page on web) then it's something related to Google.

Comment: Its on the web..My game link is.     https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.TGC.RebusFC

Comment: It's Google not you.... they will update it as soon as they feel it is time ;) I don't see the number of downloads in the link you've sent me.

Comment: It affects the ranking of my app as well?

Comment: No, they (Google) aggregate it - all is fine man. I'm sure your game is at least 4.6 ;)

Comment: Atleast 4.6? What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, it's perfectly normal.
Play Store usually takes some time to reflect the new data. Usually previous day data is shown on the next day.
And yeah this doesn't affect the rating, etc.